# Is it possible to view a SQL query in the PgAdmin III Graphical Query Builder?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I often use pgadmin III's graphical query builder to design my SQL queries. I can then toggle back to the SQL Editor tab, and grab the SQL.

Is it possible to paste a SQL query in to the SQL Editor tab, then toggle to Graphical Query Builder to see the graphical representation? I'm coming from an MS Access background, and wondering if similar functionality exists.

Comment: ... have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. The graphical query builder tab is just blank when I move to it after writing SQL in the SQL Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a one-way street. You can use the [GQB](http://pgadmin.org/docs/1.22/gqb.html#gqb) to generate SQL code but not the other way round.

I have been involved with pgAdmin development for a couple of years and I don't know of any features in the opposite direction. So I am pretty sure.